# Laravel Multi-Step Forms with One-To-Many Data Model Implementation

Tags: forms, laravel, relationship, one-to-many, multi-step

I have a one-to-many data model which need to be populated through a multi-step forms. Is there any boilerplate or general guideline to implement this in Laravel?

Let say there is this Company and Employee models with one-to-many relationship. Now, with this multi-step form how to create a Company with N Employees in one transaction?

I know how to implement one-to-many relationship but need a solution about how to persist the parent and children data when navigating forms back and forth.

Thank you!

Comment: see the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: My question is how to persist the data when navigating between multi-step forms. I know how to implement one-to-many relationship but need a solution about how to persist the parent and children data when navigating forms back and forth.